# java.util.Date in net.java.ao.Entity

Tags: java, postgresql, date, calendar, entity

I have a problem with saving data. Need to have Date field in my entity, but get error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "TIME" cannot be cast to type timestamp without time zone
```

my entity:

```
public interface ActivityDays extends Entity{

    String getKey();
    void setKey(String key);
    String getUsername();
    void setUsername(String userName);
    Date getDate();
    void setDate(Date Date);
}
```

creating date with

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

I know that Date (as same as Timestamp) doesn't have Timezone. Tried a lot of things to do.
Is there a possibility to save Date in entities (not in long format)?

Comment: One option could be to change the  date elements in the `CollectionCalendar` class to be `java.util.Date`

Comment: Can I have a link for this, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you need to be using `java.sql.Timestamp`. It has a constructor that takes milliseconds as a long:

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
```

And then on your interface, use Timestamp instead of Date.

Comment: Problem solved. Tables in PostgreSQL was not abled to update. + Used Timestamp. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found old tables in postgresql, deleted them and generated new. + Used Timestamp instead of Date. Now it works.